# Django Rest API: Using both token authentication and session authentication

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I've tried to implement two ways of logging into the Django API: token-based authentication and session authentication.

Token based authentication works fine when session based authentication isn't implemented, but when I activate session based authentication, the token based authentication endpoint only returns ""CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect".

Now, I know with session based authentication I need to set the csrf header, but is there a way to bypass this for specific endpoints, or for when a token auth header has been included in the request?

Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: Can you share the source of the class ?

Comment: did you find any solutions for this?